# How to pass -fPIC in a try_run command

Tags: compiler-errors, cmake

I'm using the cmake command `try_run` to check for a library. This works fine in a homebrew Formula (on mac) but when executing the same script on a linux machine, I receive a warning that I must "Compile your code with -fPIC (-fPIE is not enough)."

```
In file included from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qchar.h:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qstring.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QString:1,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCrypto/qca_core.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCrypto/qca.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCrypto/QtCrypto:1,
                 from qcaossl.cpp:2:
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:1113:4: error: #error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. " "Compile your code with -fPIC (-fPIE is not enough)."
 #  error "You must build your code with position independent code if Qt was built with -reduce-relocations. "\
```

This is the try_run command:

```
try_run(RUN_RESULT COMPILE_RESULT
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${TESTCPP}
  CMAKE_FLAGS "-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=11"
              "-DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON"
              "${QCA_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}"
              "${QCA_LINK_LIBRARIES}"
  COMPILE_OUTPUT_VARIABLE COMPILE_OUTPUT
)
```

When I look at the produced code that is used to compile the test code, `-fPIE` is passed to the compiler. If the directive `-DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON` is removed, `-fPIE` disappears.

I tried setting `"-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fPIC"` but this didn't help either.

What could be going wrong here?